# Swift generic function with clousure

Tags: swift, generics

I've the following generic function (not part of any class):

```
func execFuncWithGenericParameter<T, U>(f: (T) -> U){
    print(f("Hello World"))
}
```

I'd like to call this function in with a closure like this:

```
execFuncWithGenericParameter(f: { (p: String) -> Int in
    print(p)
    return 4711
})
```

But the compiler (iPad Swift Playground) tells me that "(String) -> U is not convertible to (T) -> U".

Naturelly I've done done some investigation and was the opinion that the Compiler automatically will infer the types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types are being inferred as far as the nature of `f: (T) -> U` is concerned. The problem is the *call* to `f` inside your first method.

Ask yourself: what if T were *not* String? Then `f("Hello world")` would be illegal. That is the quandary you've left the compiler with — and it rightly refuses to deal with it.

Here's a legal version:

```
func execFuncWithGenericParameter<T,U>(f: ((T) -> U), param:T){
    f(param)
}

execFuncWithGenericParameter(f: { (p: String) -> Int in
    print(p)
    return 4711
}, param:"Hello")
```

Now the first method *knows* that `param` will be a T, so all is well. And in the second method, when we *call* the first method, T is String and `param` *is* a String, so it compiles (and runs, and prints).